# SQL Problem - Duplicate Names, listing all fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I think I have a generally easy SQL problem I need help with.  I have a table I need to use which has the following fields: pmsid, ssn, lname, fname, rc, and budcode.  Some of these fields are obvious, the others aren't important to my question.

I need to list the records in this set that have duplicate first names and last names.  So if Joe Blow appears twice, I want his name to be on this list.  **I also need to show the other fields in the record**.  Simple so far?

I created the following SQL statement, which correctly lists the first and last names of the records in question.  If I include all fields, I get no records at all.  Here is what works so far:

> SELECT lname, fname FROM [Employee]
>   WHERE lname != ' 'AND fname != ' '
>   GROUP BY lname, fname
>   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Then I tried to do the following to get the other fields listed, but I get an error, obviously:

> SELECT * FROM [Employee]
>   WHERE lname, fname in

```
(SELECT lname, fname FROM [Employee]  
WHERE lname != ' 'AND fname != ' '  
GROUP BY lname, fname  
HAVING COUNT(lname) > 1 and COUNT(fname) > 1)
```

> ORDER BY lname, fname

I know I can't use multiple fields in the WHERE clause, but I'm not sure what else to try.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Concatenate the WHERE `where lname || fname in (select lname||fname from ...)`.  Of course I'm not sure how you concatenate in SQL Server, in Postgres it's the double pipe, in SQL Server it might be the `+` or the `&`, you'll have to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're that far off in your original solution, I'd just try appending the names to have one field instead of two, like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Employee]
WHERE lname + ', ' + fname in 
(SELECT lname + ', ' + fname as fullname FROM [Employee]
WHERE lname != ' ' AND fname != ' '
GROUP BY lname + ', ' + fname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

there are many other approaches which would also work, and a couple have been posted already.

Comment: this has been my solution in the past with LTRIM & RTRIM added which takes care of some of the typographical errors.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an identity field or some other unique identifier for each row?  If so, you could do a self join:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee as E
INNER JOIN Employee as E2 
ON e.fname = e2.fname and e.lname = e2.lname
WHERE e.id <> e2.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no true unique identifier in this table.  There should be, but there really is not.

Comment: @robert - is there some other field you can use to differentiate between "good" and "bad" copies of the duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM aggregate function to achieve this:
Sample Query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT  pmsid, 
                ssn, 
                lname, 
                fname, 
                rc, 
                budcode, 
                SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY lname, fname) tsum
          FROM [Employee] a
       ) b
 WHERE  tsum > 1
```

Edit: Removed Order by Clause

Comment: Since I'm a newbie, I copied this example to my query window and tried to run it.  I get "incorrect syntax near 'order'".  If I just run the inner Select statement, I get "incorrect syntax near 'DESC'".

Comment: Let me try with sometest data and get back to you

Comment: As a fix I removed the Order by Clause. Try it now.

Comment: This also worked beautifully! And it would work for any combination of fields as long as I change the partition fields.  Awesome solution!